# Automatically sent email from a my web app on particular day of every month

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application, I have a scenario like this. In 5th  day of every month, certain users has to be fetched from the database and email should be sent to them as alert. What is the best approach to handle this scenario in a web application ? Is it a best approach to monitor by putting a timer on the Global.asax file? (My requirement doesn't allow me to do it using database job).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about database job to schedule to run periodically?

Comment: I don't have permission to use job. I have edited the question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement. I did some research and found that writing a service would be the best approach, which I think requires full Visual Studio and we cannot afford that yet.

I found a thread on the ASP.NET forums helpful:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1525428.aspx/1

From the various links in that thread I was most attracted to the solution below:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

Session_Start in global.asax is something that would be triggered every time somebody visits your website. The reason we're not jumping at this solution is because we're worried that relying on somebody to hit the site to trigger Session_Start is a little unreliable, especially as we want our alerts to start going out at 10am every day.